# VIM set cursor position in Command Line

Tags: vim, text-cursor

I would like to the following in Vim:

I have this remap in the .vimrc file

```
:noremap <C-r> :Ack!  /home/user/somefolder/
```

This is so I can search in [Ack](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim) in a predefined path (somefolder), but when I use `<C-r>` to trigger this, the cursor stays at the end of the path, so then I have to use the arrows to go back to just after `Ack!` because `Ack!` expects the search term before the path.

Is there anyway I can configure this remap to put the cursor before the path?, so I can trigger `<C-r>` and immediately start writing the search term.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's easy:

```
:noremap <C-r> :Ack!  /home/user/somefolder/<C-Left><Left>
```

Just like most command-line mappings are concluded with a `<CR>` to trigger the command, you can also use cursor movements (this is also handy in insert-mode mappings and abbreviations).

Comment: Thanks! This works as expected, I knew about <Left>, but I thought it only worked to navigate in the code.